# Nonlinear Lie group from Fulton & Harris

Tags: linear-algebra, representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, diagonalization

On page 138 of my copy of the celebrated *Representation Theory* by Fulton & Harris, a proof is outlined to show that the real group of $3\times 3$ upper-triangular unipotent matrices modulo a discrete nontrivial normal subgroup (essentially $\mathbb{Z}$) does not have a faithful finite-dimensional representation. They denote this quotient group by $H$.

It starts by saying,

> "One way to see this is to argue that in any irreducible finite-dimensional representation $V$ the center $S^1$ of $H$, being compact and abelian, must be diagonalizable."

This doesn't seem right. Rotations of the plane are quite visibly **not** diagonalizable over $\mathbb{R}$. Why does "compact and abelian" imply "diagonalizable"?

Comment: Are you sure they do not mean complex representations?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft -- Yes. They are specifically talking about the real case.

Comment: I suspect that although the ("reduced Heisenberg") group itself is made from real matrices, R-and-H refer to complex representations, as @TobiasKildetoft suggests.

Comment: @paulgarrett -- Ah! It appears you are both correct. Thank you!